# javascript global variable scope issue: not showing updated value at the end of the code

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

I have a couple of global variables to tally some totals: `items` and `totalPrice`

I initialize them WITHOUT VAR after reading about this [hoisting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553661/global-variable-in-function-not-updating), I see them correctly updated during the for loop, but then at the end they have their starting value, so I must have some other mistake.

Here's a shortened version of my code:

```js
items = [];
totalPrice = 0;
for (let [key, val] of lineItems.entries()){
    console.log("toyID " + key + ", with quantity: " + val);
    Toy.findOne( { id: key }, (err, toy) => {
        if (parseInt(val) > 0){
                var subtotal = val * toy.price;
                var thisItem = {"item": key, "qty": val, "subtotal": subtotal};
                totalPrice += subtotal;      // shows correctly updated price
                items.push(thisItem);
                console.log("items now has: ", items);  // shows items
        }
    });
}
console.log("At the end, totalPrice has: ", totalPrice);  // here this is 0
console.log("At the end, Items has: ", items);     // here this is empty again
```

Is there another wrinkle getting in the way of those global variables keeping their updated value?