# Why is a global variable not being updated inside a function that is NOT redeclaring it as a local variable?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, hoisting

Before anyone asks if I reviewed other questions, I did find this one (link below paragraph) and updated one of my variables because it was redeclared as a `local variable`. It should now be `hoisted` as a `global` with precedence.

[Global variable in function not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553661/global-variable-in-function-not-updating)

I'm basically trying to get a *Next Payment Time* for a crypto-mining website. Currently, I'm able to grab the **Last Payment Time** and **Payment Interval**. The math isn't the issue... the problem I run in to is that when I grab the `variables` (from inside a `function`, they are not updating the `global` one.

**Original Declaration @ `Global`**

```
<script>
        let pendingPaymentTrigger = false;
        let timeInterval = 0;
        let pendingPayment = 0;
 /** Script Below **/
```

Then we break into the `function`, which I'm redacting due to most of it not being relevant to recreate the issue.

```
function values(baseAPI, minersAPI, activeMinersAPI, workersAPI) {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf("address") > -1) {
                const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                const wallet = urlParams.get('address');
                yourAPI = minersAPI + "?method=" + wallet;
                $("#walletRequest").hide();
                $("dashboardDisplay").show();
                const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
                XHR.open("GET", yourAPI, true);
                XHR.onload = function() {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    if (obj.body.primary?.payments?.balances === undefined || obj.body.primary?.payments?.generate === undefined) {
                            document.getElementById('pendingPayments').innerHTML = "Innactive";
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('pendingPayments').innerHTML = Math.round((obj.body.primary.payments.balances + obj.body.primary.payments.generate + obj.body.primary.payments.immature) * 100) / 100 + " HVQ";
                        pendingPaymentTrigger = true;
                        pendingPayment = Math.round((obj.body.primary.payments.balances + obj.body.primary.payments.generate + obj.body.primary.payments.immature) * 100) / 100;
                        console.log(pendingPayment);
                    }
```

At this point, the `console` shows '1 Hour' || If I change from `pendingPayments` to `pendingPaymentTrigger` it shows 'True'

Right after the function ends...

```
}
console.log(pendingPayment);


let displayBlocks = new Array();
let displayBlocks2 = new Array();

function checkBlocks() { // This is the next function - not relevant, but supporting that I am **out** of the last function.
```

This `console` shows '0' (the original `global variable`).

I'm guessing it has something to do with `hoisting` but I can't figure out where the issue lies..

---

Tested theory from comments 1 - moving to the end of the function:

```
if (obj.body.primary?.payments?.balances === undefined || obj.body.primary?.payments?.generate === undefined) {
            document.getElementById('pendingPayments').innerHTML = "Innactive";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('pendingPayments').innerHTML = Math.round((obj.body.primary.payments.balances + obj.body.primary.payments.generate + obj.body.primary.payments.immature) * 100) / 100 + " HVQ";
            pendingPaymentTrigger = true;
            pendingPayment = Math.round((obj.body.primary.payments.balances + obj.body.primary.payments.generate + obj.body.primary.payments.immature) * 100) / 100;
            console.log(pendingPayment);
        }
    }
};
XHR.send();
```

This did not change the outcome - has time here, but not after.

Comment: could it be that `pendingPayment` is being updated after it's logged in the console? XHR requests are async the onload callback will run when the request is done, by that time it will already have logged `0` since unlike PHP, JS has an event loop

Comment: @Undo I moved it to the end of the function - just before the `XHR.send();` and no change.

Comment: JS is not a synchronous language, it will not wait for the onload event to be called before continuing to execute.

Comment: so you're saying it's running right past my `local` version of the variables and getting overwritten by the `global` version before the `function` / `onload` finishes?

Comment: no, I think you're just logging the variable before it changes

Comment: Possible - so we know that the variable is changing to '1 Hour' at some point (initially set to 0). We know it's not making it to the bottom of my `</script>` (which is where I'm testing the final value). I guess the question would be - how do I get it down there...

Comment: You need to either use `async/await` logic or nest your operation inside the XHR.onload. XHR.onload overwrites your global variables, the problem is that console.log runs before the XHR request has finished, since XHR is async

Comment: you can make a new function *down there* and call that function after mutating the variable in your callback

Comment: I do like the idea of another function - nice and clean that way - if you want to throw that as an answer, I'll accept it @Undo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a function after your script and call that function when the XHR request is done and you've mutated the variable.

```js
/* ... */
pendingPaymentTrigger = true;
pendingPayment = Math.round((obj.body.primary.payments.balances + obj.body.primary.payments.generate + obj.body.primary.payments.immature) * 100) / 100;
doSomething();
/* ... */
```

```js
function doSomething() {
    console.log(pendingPayment);
}
```

Comment: If you do that, better pass the value as an argument instead of relying on a global variable.

Comment: I agree but OP might have other reasons for using a global variable

Comment: The functions do so many things together. I consolidated 6 different APIs into 2 functions (5 and 1) - It would be difficult to grab the data I need and `return` it back. In addition, I've noticed that the vars done even make it out of the `XHR`. I tried doing @Undo 's suggestion, and the end result was the same.